# Inviting your friend.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The number of ways you can invite 3 of your friends on 5 consecutive days, exactly one friend a day, such that no friend is invited on more than two days is?

How should I proceed with this?
What is the best method to solve this?

The answer given is 90.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but is the answer  36 ways? If it is, then I think I have an explanation. Also, try to mention in the post what you've tried out so far. Otherwise you'll risk getting your post downvoted.

Comment: @NikilKumar No, it is 90.

Comment: alright then, I'm not sure how to proceed either.

Comment: @Tapi:  If you know the answer you should put it in the question.  $90$ is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must invite two of them twice and one once.  How many ways to choose the one you invite once? How many ways to choose the day you invite that friend?  How many ways to distribute the other two?

Comment: 3C1*5C1 should answer the first two questions. And if we choose the one we invite once, then the other two are implicitly selected. So, since 4 days are left and 2 people are yet to be invited, it should be 4C2?

Comment: @NikilKumar, 4C2 and $4!/2!*2!$ are the same thing.

Comment: oops nvm, I did not think it through. I'll delete my comment, sorry!

Comment: That is correct and results in$90$